# Meaning of "Yo más guapa"

Tags: definiciones

What's the meaning of ***¡Yo más guapa!*** in the following conversation?

> A: - ¡Toma, te quiero!
>   B: - ¡Yo más guapa!

I googled the phrase and it seems to be some kind of slogan. I'm not sure though whether it is somehow connected to what is meant here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing a comma there. The phrase should be: *yo más, guapa*.

*guapa* means *good looking* and it's a common way to affectionately address a woman in Spain. So the conversation goes more or less like this:

> A: - ¡I love you!
>   B: - ¡I love you more, gorgeous!

Answer (score 5):

I think it may need a comma

> ¡Yo más guapa!  <sub>Me more, cuttie</sub>

It is not an slogan, but a colloquial way of telling someone that you want or deserve or need something more than the other person.

> A:- No llego a fin de mes. Necesito otros 500 euros
>
> B:- Yo también, guapa

In that context `guapa` is not a colloquial way to refer to somebody, but means literally "beautiful".

> A:- ¡Te quiero!
>
> B: - ¡Yo (a tí) más, guapa!